# After cascading two routers, can't connect to the second anymore

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

I have two routers.

The "first" one is a TP-Link TL-WDR3600 and is directly connected to a cable modem which my ISP gave me. DHCP is enabled here.

The "second" one is Linksys WRT320N. This one is connected to the first router with a cable. On this one I disabled DHCP and it works well so that clients connected to the second router get an IP by the first one and have internet access.

But I have the problem that I can't connect to the second router's web interface anymore. In the first router's web interface I can't see that the second one got an IP address on which I could connect. And so I don't know how to change the config on the second one.

How can I find out the second router's IP address?
How can I change the second router's config?

Comment: It's important that your second router has a static IP *outside* the range of your DHCP pool/scope. You may need to shrink your DHCP pool if it takes an entire subnet. E.g. Router 1 (192.168.0.1 static) + Router 2 (192.168.0.2 static) + DHCP Pool (router 1)(192.168.0.100 - 192.168.0.200) giving your 100 potential devices. You'll then be able to connect to router 1 and 2 from a web browser to admin them :)

Comment: Thanks! Router 1's DHCP range is 192.168.0.100 - 192.168.0.199 (by default). But I don't know if I set a static IP for router 2. How can I find out since I don't have access to this router's web interface?

Comment: You may need to factory reset the 2nd router if you can't get to its web interface... it shouldn't be too difficult to reset it (and should only take a few minutes at most) -> give it a static IP -> turn off DHCP server -> configure wireless settings -> done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of Big Chris I solved my problem. Here I want to summarize my solution.

- I had to factory reset my 2nd router because I didn't know its IP address.
- Before doing this I looked up the default IP it uses and the default username/password.
- Then I disconnected it from the 1st router and factory reset it.
- Afterwards I could connect to it and so I set the static IP address outside the DHCP range of the 1st router and disabled DHCP.
- Then I reconnected it to the first router and everything's fine now.

Thanks @Big Chris!

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This helped me out a lot. Just wanted to add that for the WRT320N router, you can leave the "Internet Setup - Internet Connection type" section/field to just: "Automatic Configuration - DHCP". This just lets the main/primary router doing the DHCP, deal with the WAN settings. But one must disable the WRT320N's own DHCP server, further down the same page.

Comment: Also apparently there's [two ways](https://community.linksys.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/WRT320N-how-do-you-configure-it-as-a-Access-Point-or-bridged/td-p/457551) to connect two routers